# Which condition is stronger - ergodicity or mixing?

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, complex-systems

Reading a statistical physics book, I've encountered the following assertion (without further explanations):

> [..] the presence of dynamical instability makes the trajectory of a
>   system much more complex, and the system itself at least mixing, if
>   not ergodic.

I was sure that the mixing property implies ergodicity..any suggestions?

Comment: Ergodicity is stronger. It covers all possible mixing states.

Comment: I disagree with the previous comment: in the standard terminology of ergodic theory, at least, mixing is stronger than ergodicity. See, for example, the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of definitions. What do you mean by "mixing states", @user115350?

Comment: Isn't ergodicity just the property that the time-average is consistent with the temporal ensemble average?  Meaning, there is an asymptotic state to the system.

Comment: @honeste_vivere, yes, that's my understanding as well. For that to happen, a typical initial condition must visit a full measure of the phase space. But it might be able to do so in an "orderly manner", without mixing (which is why mixing is stronger).

Comment: OP, can you give us the reference for this book or at least tell which system is that?